# Attach data to Response in Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, filter, response

i'm working on a function that returns info related to two ids. And i would like to attach those ids to the response right after the success message. Here is my code:

The Controller function that make a call to another one in the Repository (that is working fine)

```
public function getCampaignEstablishments($lang, $campaignId, $companyId)
    {
        $establishments = $this->repository->allEstablishments($campaignId, $companyId);
      
        return CampaignEstablishments::collection($establishments);
    }
```

The Resource function that filters the data (for testing im displaying all of it)

```
class CampaignEstablishments extends PotatoesResource
{
    const SINGLE_KEY = 'establishment';
    const COLLECTION_KEY = 'establishments';

    public function toArray($request)
    { 

        return parent::toArray($request);

    }
}
```

And this is the imported collection Resource

```
    public static function collection($collection)
    {
        $subclass = get_called_class();

        return self::baseResource(
            $subclass::COLLECTION_KEY,
            parent::collection($collection)
        );
    }

    public static function baseResource($key, $value)
    {
        return [
            'success' => true,
            $key => $value
        ];
    }
```

Currently i'm getting this response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "establishments": [
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        },
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        },
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the response i would like to get

```
{
    "success": true,
    "campaign_id": /*the id passed in $campaignId*/
    "company_id": /*the id passed in $companyId*/
    "establishments": [
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        },
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        },
        {
            /*Data of an establishment*/
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried a lot of different ways and got a lot of different structures but not this one in particular. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return it in an associative array:

```
return [
    "success" => true,
    "campaign_id" => $campaignId,
    "company_id" => $companyId,
    "establishments" => CampaignEstablishments::collection($establishments),
];
```

UPDATED: Then you need to do this:

```
$establishments = CampaignEstablishments::collection($establishments);
$establishments['campaign_id'] = $campaignId;
$establishments['company_id'] = $companyId;

return $establishments;
```

Comment: It might return back to your AJAX call like response.data.establishments

Comment: I tried this but i got duplicated results. Then i figured that CampaignEstablishments is already returning "success" and "establishments".

Comment: If it is an array you can just added the other items